# Fazer join de 3 listas em c# a partir de consultas na base de dados

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo uma página para gerar um relatório. Neste faço 3 *selects* diferentes, colocando o resultado de cada consulta em uma lista:

```
public IEnumerable<RelatorioVencerVencidos> ObterRelatorioVencerVencidos(ParametrosVencerVencidos filtro)
    {

        var hash = new Dictionary<int, RelatorioVencerVencidos>();

        CarregarListVencerVencidos(hash,filtro);
        CombinarComDadosDeRendaFixa(hash);
        CombinarComDadosDeClubes(hash);

        return hash.Values.ToArray();
    }

    private void CombinarComDadosDeClubes(Dictionary<int, RelatorioVencerVencidos> hash)
    {
        foreach (var clubes in Instance.ObterClubesVirtual())
        {
            if (hash.ContainsKey(clubes.CodCotista))
                hash[clubes.CodCotista].Clubes = clubes.SaldoBruto;
        }
    }

    private void CombinarComDadosDeRendaFixa(Dictionary<int, RelatorioVencerVencidos> hash)
    {
        foreach (var renda in Instance.ObterRendaFixaVirtual())
        {
            var codCliente = default(int);
            if (int.TryParse(renda.CodCliente, out codCliente))
                if (hash.ContainsKey(codCliente))
                    hash[codCliente].RendaFixa = renda.ValorBruto;
        }
    }

    public void CarregarListVencerVencidos(Dictionary<int, RelatorioVencerVencidos> hash, ParametrosVencerVencidos filtros)
    {

        foreach (var i in Instance.ObterDadosVencerVencidos(filtro))
        {
            if (!hash.ContainsKey(i.CodigoBovespa))
                hash.Add(i.CodigoBovespa, i);
        }
    }
```

Estou editdando a pergunta, devido a eu ter feito da forma acima, utilizando Dictionary, onde eu carrego a listas em um dictionary utilizando o codigo do cliente como a chave e pego o saldo do cliente como valor do dictionary.
Apenas uma unica coisa que não esta dando muito certo é devido ao meu metodo ObterDadosVencerVencidos que esta no ultimo foreach que recebe alguns parametros e os parametro acabam vindo zerados sendo que no metodo ObterRelatorioVencerVencidos os Parametros estão com valores, porem quando entra no metodo CarregarListVencerVencidos os parametros ficam nulos e não estou conseguindo saber a forma correta para pegar as informações dos parametros no metodo ObterDadosVencerVencidos.

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: O erro é esse abaixo nas duas linhas que destaquei como erro na pergunta:

The best overload method match for 'System.Colections.Generic.list<RelatorioVencerVencidos>.AddRange(System.collections.
Generic.Ienumerable<RelatorioVencerVencidos>)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que a questão é relacionada a conceitos de orientação a objetos.
Ocorre que sua variável "join" não possui o mesmo tipo de "listaclubes" e "listarelatorios".
A declaração de "join" deveria ser:

```
List<IDadosVencerVencidos> join = new List<IDadosVencerVencidos>(listaRendaFixa.Count + listaClubes.Count + listaRelatorio.Count);
```

Este exemplo que fiz funciona corretamente:

Criar a interface

```
interface IDados
{
    int Codigo { get; set; }
    String  Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
class Cliente : IDados
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public DateTime Aniversario { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
class Fornecedor : IDados
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Cliente> lstCliente = new List<Cliente>();
        lstCliente.Add(new Cliente { Codigo = 1, Descricao = "C1", Aniversario = DateTime.Now });
        lstCliente.Add(new Cliente { Codigo = 2, Descricao = "C2", Aniversario = DateTime.Now });
        lstCliente.Add(new Cliente { Codigo = 3, Descricao = "C3", Aniversario = DateTime.Now });


        List<Fornecedor> lstFornecedor = new List<Fornecedor>();
        lstFornecedor.Add(new Fornecedor { Codigo = 100, Descricao = "F1", Endereco = "End. 1" });
        lstFornecedor.Add(new Fornecedor { Codigo = 200, Descricao = "F2", Endereco = "End. 2" });


        List<IDados> lstJoin = new List<IDados>(lstCliente.Count + lstFornecedor.Count);

        lstJoin.AddRange(lstCliente);
        lstJoin.AddRange(lstFornecedor);

        foreach (IDados d in lstJoin)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("> {0} - {1}", d.Codigo, d.Descricao));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

O resultado final é uma lista contento 5 objetos do tipo "IDados".

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, Declarei utilizando a minha interface, porem na hora do return join, ainda estava dando erro de conversão.

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta e adicionar o novo código, de preferência com a implementação das classes?

Comment: Pergunta editada Editada Tomas. Pode dar uma ajuda ?

Comment: Que tipo de objeto o método Instance.ObterDadosVencerVencidos retorna? Adicione a estrutura desse objeto na pergunta (com métodos e propriedades), aí acho que podemos resolver o problema. Quanto ao fato dos parâmetros nulos, é preciso saber também qual o tipo da variável filtro, onde está sendo declarada e os locais onde sofre alteração. Pelo código exposto não é possível inferir nada a respeito.

Comment: Tomas, Editei novamente a questão, eu estava passando apenas como parametro hash no metodo CarregarListVencerVencidos, sendo que eu não estava passando como parametro o meu filtro tambem, então resumindo: Passei como parametro a minah var hash, e tambem ParametrosVencerVencidos filtro, e com isso não perdi os valores dos parametros quando entrava no método. Agradeço sua ajuda.